# mysql ssl connection hangs

Tags: mysql, openssl, connection

in a nutshell - trying to connect to a mysql server on host 'a' using the sql command-line interface on host 'b' over the internet with an open-ssl encrypted connection, the connection attempt hangs indefinitely. the connection succeeds normally when a non-ssl connection is attempted between the same machines.

### O/S

the server is CentOS version 6.4
the client is CentOS version 6.5

### SSL

on the server -

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
```

on the client -

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
```

the certificates on both sides were self-generated, following the instructions in example 1 at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/creating-ssl-certs.html, except for '`rsa:2048 -days 3600`', which i changed to '`rsa:3072 -days 3653`'.

### MYSQL

over a non-encrypted connection from the client machine to the server, i get the following information -

```
Server version: 5.1.69-log Source distribution
SSL:                    Not in use
TCP port:               3306

mysql> show variables like '%ssl%';
+---------------+-------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                               |
+---------------+-------------------------------------+
| have_openssl  | YES                                 |
| have_ssl      | YES                                 |
| ssl_ca        | /etc/ssl/certs/ca-cert.pem          |
| ssl_capath    |                                     |
| ssl_cert      | /etc/ssl/certs/server-cert.pem      |
| ssl_cipher    | {truncated for readability}         |
| ssl_key       | /etc/ssl/certs/server-key.pem       |
+---------------+-------------------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.08 sec)
```

[i've truncated the ssl-cipher line in the above dump because the list of ciphers takes up several lines of output.]

the server is started without the '`--ssl*`' command-line arguments, but the appropriate lines exist in `my.cnf`.

the cli is invoked as -

```
mysql --ssl-ca=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-cert.pem --ssl-cert=/etc/ssl/certs/client-cert.pem --ssl-key=/etc/ssl/certs/client-key.pem -u "$DBUSER" -p"$DBPW" -h "$DBSERVER" $DBNAME
```

the client version is -

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

i've checked for network routing and firewall issues, and none of the firewalls, iplist policies, or routers are denying any packets as far as i can see. also, in both encrypted and non-encrypted cases, `netstat` shows the connection as '`ESTABLISHED`', so the problem doesn't appear to be at the network level.

i think i must have something wrong with the ssl configuration, but i don't know what.
any help appreciated !

Comment: Are you sure the ports are open?  SSL and non-SSL is normally different ports.  You could probably run a nbstat of sort to see if it is even trying (or how far it is getting)

Comment: yes, the networking engineer verified this. he says that both are coming in on port 3306 whether encrypted or not, and aren't being blocked.

Answer (score 2):

this turned out to be a network-related issue after all. the firewall guarding the server, a palo alto networks 3000-series, believed the handshake sequence could contain a threat corresponding to [CVE-2006-1517](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2006-1517), so while it allowed the tcp/ip packet, it subsequently performed a `DROP ALL PACKETS` action after analyzing the content. the solution was to change the firewall's configuration to allow these kinds packets from the client machine without generating the fault.

Comment: Glad to hear it is fixed.  Bugger to solve these types.